# CF 11. 'ColdFusion is not defined' error using ColdFusion.Ajax.submitForm

Tags: iis, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

Just re-installed everything on new laptop after old one crashed. Upgraded from CF9 to CF11 in the process. Running IIS on Windows 10. Local site is working fine, except when it comes to submitting a form with ajax.

```
ColdFusion.Ajax.submitForm('registerForm', '/register_action.cfm', callback,errorHandler);
```

- I have `<cfajaximport>` at the top.
- I have an IIS virtual CFIDE directory
  pointing to `C:\ColdFusion2016\cfusion\wwwroot\CFIDE`
- Mapping in CFAdmin is correct

There was not issue with CF9. But I notice CF11 has its scripts directory OUTSIDE the CFIDE directory on the same level (directory named "cf_scripts"), whereas CF9 has the scripts INSIDE the CFIDE directory.

Before I stuff things up, has anyone any pointers in the right direction?

### SOLUTION

For the benefit of others, I did the following:

- CFAdministrator `Default ScriptSrc` directory: `/CF_SCRIPTS`
- IIS Virtual Directory: `CF_SCRIPTS` pointing to `C:\ColdFusion2016\cfusion\wwwroot\cf_scripts\scripts\`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a virtual directory in IIS that points to that scripts folder.

In the ColdFusion administrator, under the Server > Settings tab, make sure the *Default ScriptSrc Directory* name matches the IIS virtual directory name you created.